# Chrome developer tools (How to know I am calling which javascript object)

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, developer-tools

I first create a breakpoint into one line of JavaScript(inside the JavaScript class). Then I step by step go to ***next function call F11***. With the developer tools, I reach to the following code.

`var p = this.rotator.playing;`

In this condition I know the ***variable inside class*** and the ***class name***
But I want to know now I am ***calling which object*** for that class. Any suggestion?

Actually I want to modify the variable `p` from outside of the JavaScript class.

Comment: We will get the value of `this.rotator.playing` from console(of chrome developer tools) just at that breakpoint. And so we can modify the value of `this.rotator.playing` at that point as well. But I can't modify from outside as I don't know which now which object is now in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Watch Expression for each object that you are unsure of and whichever is currently used will have a value.

Not sure if this is an answer. It's not a very great question worded the way it is.

Comment: I don't know the name of object and the object is not global. `this.rotator.playing` is the script on compressed js file. I can modify something on that compressed near the code `this.rotator.playing` but I cannot modify `this.rotator.playing` externally. Can Watch Expression help on that?

Comment: Well, you could do this:

Open up the compressed file in the Sources panel and click the {} icon to pretty print the code so it's readable.
Then do either Ctrl + Shift + O to search for the method or property this object is contained within, or alternatively, Ctrl + F to simply find the line number it is on.
Finally, you could add a breakpoint on that line by clicking on the line number gutter for the line the object is on.
OR, you can right click on the gutter for that line number and choose to Continue to here,

Comment: or add a Conditional breakpoint which you can specify conditions for which it should break on that line for.
When you do this, you can then view the objects properties/values in the Scope Variables sidebar, as well as add view the object in the Watch expressions, if you were to have set one up for this.rotator.playing since it would at that particular time in the script execution be in the scope and should exist, with it's call stack as well shown in the sidebar.